# How to time a reactive input update in R shiny for inputs in renderUI/uiOutput block that haven't been created yet?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-reactivity

In an app I'm trying to implement some "restore settings" functionality, but I'm having trouble restoring the values of dynamically created inputs. I've created a simple example to illustrate my problem.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("num_sliders", "Number of sliders:",
                        min = 0,max = 10, value = 0),
            actionButton("load1", "Load v1"),
            actionButton("load2", "Load v2"),
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           uiOutput("dynamic_sliders")
        )
    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
    rv = reactiveValues()
    rv$restored_inputs = FALSE
    output$dynamic_sliders = renderUI({
        req(input$num_sliders > 0)
        fluidRow(tagList(
            lapply(1:input$num_sliders,
            function (n)
                column(3, sliderInput(paste0("slider", n),
                                      paste("Slider", n),
                                      min = 0, max = 9, value = 0)))
        ))
    })

    observeEvent(input$load1, {
        updateSliderInput(session, "num_sliders", value = 3)
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value = 5)
    })

    observeEvent(input$load2, {
        updateSliderInput(session, "num_sliders", value = 3)
        rv$restored_inputs = TRUE

    })

    observe({
        req(rv$restored_inputs)
        updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value = 5)
        rv$restored_inputs = FALSE
    }, priority = -999)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I press "Load v1" it's clear the problem is that I'm trying to update an input that hasn't been created yet (the output is invalidated, but not recalculated before I try to update the value).

What's not clear is why "Load v2" doesn't solve the problem. After I update num_sliders, I instead trigger a reactive value. Both the renderUI and observe blocks get invalidated. I thought that because I lowered the observe blocks priority, the renderUI block would recalculate first, and then the input slider would exist at the time I try to update it's value.

I tried using reactLog to work through the invalidations but I still can't seem to figure it out. Anyone know how I can force the desired execution order?

The problem obviously doesn't happen for either load button if num_sliders is manually changed to be greater than 0 before testing.

I've looked into some of the native bookmarking features of Rshiny and don't think they're a solution in this case, as in the full app I need very tight control of what gets restored when in order to maintain performance.

Comment: Can you describe the steps you have which recreates the problem? When you run the app, what do you do exactly, what happens currently in the app, and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: When I click load, I want it to update the "num_sliders" value to 3. The UI should then update to show 3 sliders, and the value of one of the sliders should be changed from it's default value to 5. Right now I get it updated to have 3 sliders, but the value of the new slider isn't changed like I want it. If you click twice on either button, it will work (hence my comment about needing to test it without changing num_sliders).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I think one approach would be to track your slider values as a `reactiveValues`. If you add `slider_vals = NULL` in your `reactiveValues`, you can set with your `observeEvent(input$load`,...` by using `rv$slider_vals = c(5,0,0)` for example, instead of `updateSliderInput` for `slider1`. Then, in creating your dynamic sliders, use `value = rv$slider_vals[n]` so when it creates the slider it uses the right value.

Comment: Let me know if this will work for your needs. Also happy to provide a more detailed answer if you'd like, no problem.

Comment: To do the solution above, you will also need to track the slider values every time the dynamic sliders change. Otherwise when you change the number of sliders, slider 1 and/or 2 will reset to 5. Or capture the values before updating the dynamic UI area, but ignoring certain ones depending of if the change is triggered by the load buttons or interaction with the selector

Comment: If you haven't looked into it, check out [Shiny bookmarking state](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html). It can get sticky with dynamic UI elements, but check out this [RStudio forum post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookmarking-state-and-dynamic-output/2614/4) to see if it helps

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't think the suggestions are quite going to work for me.

The onRestore option for shiny bookmarking is basically adding extra overhead by repeating specific update inputs. It works for the example I created here, but will not work in the full app I'm developing.

Comment: As for Marcus' suggestion: I'm designing a module template for users to be able to extend the app. The convention is that when you bookmark settings in a module, all performance-intensive calculations are restored to an rv, instead of replicating the full calculation by specifying the inputs. Once those are restored, non-intense calculations are done by restoring the settings (e.g., renaming a graph label). Requiring users to write custom tracking code for dynamic inputs would break the abstraction.